# Record Lock in salesforce

Tags: record, locking

How to record lock once status is completed as per UI, but in backend using automation process we can like roll up field ,record can be updated

Answer (score 0):

Update the record type for the record, and assign a page layout to that record type that marks all fields as "read only".

Doing that at the page layout level instead of in FLS means that it doesn't restrict Apex from making changes (the restrictions are only applied to input via the UI).